# Why google storage don't accept direct uploads from Rails Active Storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage

I'm using google cloud storage in my application. Until last week everything were working fine, i've change nothing and now my files aren't beeing sent to storage.

The following message is displayed when I **submit the form** with the file.

[image]

and in the console has a link that display this
[image]

One curious thing is that i can normally sent the images from Rails Console

```
config.logo.attach(io:File.open(Rails.root.join('public/images/default.png')), filename: 'default.png', content_type:'application/png');
```

If using local storage everything works fine too.

Using Ruby 2.5.1, Rails 5.2.2 and Active Storage with Direct Uploads.

UPDATE
My form

```
<%= form_for @config, multipart: true do |f| %>
    <div class="row  border-bottom white-bg dashboard-header">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Configs</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-lg-5">                
            <%= image_tag f.object.logo, clas: 'img-fluid' if f.object.logo.attached? %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :logo %>
                <%= f.file_field :logo, direct_upload: true,  class:"form-control form-resource" %>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Salvar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

When I remove `direct_upload: true`, works fine, but I don't want remove this functionality

Comment: Please include the code you are using to handle the form and do the upload.

Comment: Done and when i remove direct_upload: true it works

Comment: Nothing in that code actually references GCS, can you share the model/controller that actually uses GCS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by configuring CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin